# VBA power operator (^) not working as expected in 64-bit VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I feel foolish for asking and I'm sure there's a simple answer. I'm trying to get a power for a number as follows:

```
Sub test()

Dim number As Long

number = 2^8 ' Expect to get 256 here

End Sub
```

This produces an error: 'Expected: list separator or )'.

I'm surprised this doesn't work. I'm aware that there's an Excel defined power function. But is the ^ operator not supported in VBA - it is in VB6?

**FURTHER INFO**

If I do the same in the Immediate window, I get the following strangeness (no error):

```
?2^8
 2  8
```

It looks like just spaces between the 2 and the 8.

**IT WORKS?**

So I was messing about with various combinations of symbols and found that in the Immediate window:

```
?2^^8
 256
```

What the...? Anyone know why this might be?

**MORE EXPERIMENTS**

I'm guessing my installation of Excel must be broken (although absolutely everything else works fine). Some further things the Immediate window:

If I insert a space before ^:

```
?2 ^3
 8

?2!^3
 8

?2"^3
 2 ^3

?2£^3
 2  0  3

?2%^3
 8

?2@^3
 8

?2#^3
 8
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Is there any other code in your program? Note that you're not currently outputting your number at all though.

Comment: I've stripped it right down to the above and still get the error.

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/carrot-operator) states that this is a valid operator in VBA. Which line does it fail on?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through to see what line it fails at, or hitting "Debug" > "Compile Project"?

Comment: The line having number = 2^8 is in red, so it won't compile.

Comment: Works fine here. What are your locale settings?

Comment: I doubt its the cause but click tools->references - is "visual basic for applications" checked?  Does the problem persist in a new empty workbook?

Comment: @AlexK I don't think it's possible to remove the VBA reference.

Comment: @AlexK the reference is checked.

Comment: Yea, but I didn't think it was possible for an operator to effectively disappear, so you never know.

Comment: @VincentG I'm in Windows, my region is United Kingdom and display language English (United States), keyboard is UK layout.

Comment: Regarding your edit, `2  8` is the expected output for `?2&8`.

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips hey, I get this too... and your post helped me. Do you happen to be using 64bit VBA? I am.

Comment: @SlowLearner yes, 64bit VBA.

Comment: I think, then, that you have uncovered an oddity - there are a few quirky things with the 64Bit ver of VBA, this is one of them. IIRC the 32 bit version will autocorrect `2^3` to `2 ^ 3` (which is what we are used to with VBA) so this was driving me nuts for a little too long... thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Confirmed: Also happens in MS Word 2010, 2013, 2016 all 64 bit Office*1

> **1 I suspect this applies to most of, if not all, the 64 bit office applications*

This seems to be an issue with the 64 bit version of MS Office.  In the 32 bit version the caret `^` is used for the power operator, however in the 64 bit operator it is also used for variables of type LongLong ([learn.microsoft.com/.../vba/.../longlong-data-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type)).

In 64 bit VBA, when using `Debug.Print`*2 the IDE auto corrects `2^2` to `2^; 2` but `2 ^2` is auto-corrected to `2 ^ 2`; making the code compile-able.

By way of a solution, this is just one of those annoying things that users of 64bit VBA *'just need to know'.*

---

Edit: Microsoft confirmed issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2454019/the-64-bit-office-2010-vba-compiler-shows-an-error-when-it-encounters

**2 I've also come to learn that the VBA behavior is different when using `debug.Print` than assigning a variable (thanks to [@ErikvonAsmuth](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43958909#43958909))*

Comment: It's a breaking change, but it's the intended effect of adding the LongLong type, so probably best not to use loaded words like "issue" or "properly corrected".

Comment: @BenVoigt lol - fixed, tnx

Comment: @BenVoigt hmmm breaking change... not sure on that, the language syntax has not changed; existing code will not stop working... In the 64 bit VBA IDE the auto-correct simply does not work as one may expect from using the 32 bit version. I imagine had this been VS (and not the VBA IDE) that the behavior would be modified fairly quickly; I do see where you're coming from though, but I reckon it could be fixed and the Rubberduck project (http://rubberduckvba.com/) might just do that so I don't think the terms are overly loaded... VBA just needs some love. Cheers

Comment: I guess you're saying that existing code that's been run through autocorrect in the 32-bit version will not stop working.  But existing code that's been edited without autocorrect help might contain `2^y`, and the way that parses has changed (was a binary operator, now a type suffix).

Comment: Basically yes - but on reflection I imagine the biggest trap would probably come from copying and pasting chunks of code from places like SO...

Comment: It's been a while since I used VBA, but I thought pasting triggered autocorrect (if enabled)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180171/discussion-between-slowlearner-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's not broken! I shouldn't have been so hasty to close the question. The real question is, what @?!* thought it was a good idea to use a ^ to denote a longlong? Why not use some other symbol. Maybe an @ perhaps? Oh well.

Comment: Yeah... I was thinking they could have used ```~```

Comment: As a further thing to note. You'll get the same behaviour with other 'overloaded' symbols, such as & and ! . If you leave the space out before the symbol it will be treated as a numerical type instead of an operator.

Comment: I'd never really noticed that... I often use ```Debug.Print``` and that seems to give different results. Good learning today :-D

Comment: In response to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264287/vba-power-operator-not-working-as-expected-in-64-bit-vba/52360094#comment91672643_52360094 (what @?!* thought it was a good idea to use a ^ to denote a longlong?), I'd like to draw your attention to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.goto) and suggest it was the same person.

Comment: So...this should be considered a "compiler bug" and not an "undocumented feature", right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the powerfunction. For example

```
Sub Test()
Dim number As Long
number = Application.WorksheetFunction.power(2, 8)
End Sub
```

But the ^ operator must have been working too .

Comment: There should be no need for a developer to resort to a `WorksheetFunction` for one of the languages built-in operators.