# How to write equation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I am stuck on how to enter the following equation in to VBA so that Cell A1 will can change the value of X. X=0.5
[image: Equation]

Here is my code in VBA:

```
Sub Equation()

Dim x As Double
x = Range("A1").Value
Answer = Sqr(1 + x ^ 2) & (1 + (1) / Sqr(1 + x ^ 2))

MsgBox ("The Answer to the equation is " & Answer)
End Sub
```

Comment: So the problem is the equation? Can you let us know what the correct result would be with some examples? In this example, would the answer be  2.12?

Comment: Wow, I totally misinterpreted that question.  Wrote an answer saying that you can't write the equation  in Excel without referencing Word.  Still with noting here for those who think like my....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.OMath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a module into you VBA project:

[image]

write below function there:

```
Function func(x As Double) As Double
    Dim result As Double

    result = x * Exp(Sqr(1 + x * x))
    result = result * (1 + 1 / (Sqr(1 + x * x)))
    func = result
End Function
```

And then use it in worksheet like: `=func(A1)`

**NOTE**: [`^` operator doesn't work everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264287/vba-power-operator-not-working-as-expected-in-64-bit-vba)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few parts of your expression. First, **e** is not defined, and it is also not part of your expression. Have a look at this:

```
e = 2.7182818284
Answer = (x * e ^ Sqr(1 + x ^ 2)) * (1 + 1 / Sqr(1 + x ^ 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help when i do the calculation on the calculator and math way 0.5 * 2.7182818284 √1+0.5^2   * ( 1+ 1\√1+0.5^2 )  the answer i get is 2.878706652.   Should the equation in excel be  (x * e * Sqr(1 + x ^ 2)) * (1 + 1 / Sqr(1 + x ^ 2)) i replaced (x * e ^Sqr to (x * e *  Sqr

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be an actual function do this ( @sam has the equation for you ).

```
Function Equation(x as Double) as Double

Dim e = As Double 

e = 2.7182818284

Equation = (x * e ^ Sqr(1 + x ^ 2)) * (1 + 1 / Sqr(1 + x ^ 2))

End Function
```

Now in B1 you could do `=Equation(A1)`

Answer (score 1):

a) To enter your math formula, you need to know the syntax:

- To get the square root, use `Sqr` (you did already)
- The power function is done with the ^ (caret) character
- There is no build in constant `e`, you can define it either by defining a constant or use `Exp(1)`

b) If you want to use your equation available in your Excel, create a *UDF* (User Defined Function).

Have a look at the following piece of code. I like to split complicated statements into pieces, so I have used 2 intermediate variables.

If your `x` is in `A1`, you can for example write the Formula `=Equation(A1)` into cell `B1`.

```
Public Function Equation(x As Double) As Double    
    Dim term1 As Double, term2 As Double, answer As Double
    term1 = Sqr(1 + x ^ 2)
    term2 = 1 + (1 / term1)
    Equation = x * (Exp(1) ^ term1) * term2
End Function
```