# Pythagorean Formula in VBA - Exponents and Power

Tags: vba

```
N1 = 3
N2 = 4
N3 = Sqr(N1^(2) + N2^(2)) 'N3 is the hypotenuse
MsgBox N3
```

I get the following error and `N1^` is highlight.

[image]

Comment: Runs just fine when I test it like that, so you must have other code that is declaring the variables as something incorrect. Try using `Option Explicit` and define all of your variable appropriately.

Comment: Seems like Microsoft introduced a bug with 64-bit VBA when some programmer decided that `^` was a character which could be safely used for `Long Long` type declarations. It is a mystery why anyone thought that there was a need to have any type declaration character for a new data type since such ways of declaring type is ancient cruft in VBA, and it is even more of a mystery why someone thought that the exponentiation operator would be a good choice. An astonishingly bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some issues with the power operator, please refer to this thread:

[VBA power operator (^) not working as expected in 64-bit VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264287/vba-power-operator-not-working-as-expected-in-64-bit-vba)

Also temporary fix to this issue mentioned in this thread, use the below function to calculate power:

```
Excel.WorksheetFunction.Power(N1, 2)
```

---

Edit: for Powerpoint VBA, I'm not sure if there's a library function that would calculate the power, but for integer type of power number, we can simply wrap a loop into a function:

```
Public Function myPower(base As Double, pow As Long) As Double
    Dim ret As Double: ret = 1

    If pow > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To pow
            ret = ret * base
        Next i
    Else
        For i = -1 To pow Step -1
            ret = ret / base
        Next i
    End If

    myPower = ret
End Function
```

For floating point power number... I'll have to go back and check the formula....

---

Second Edit: I just tested putting parenthesis on the variables then using caret, seems to be working on my 64bit Excel, maybe you should try this in PowerPoint first :)

```
Public Sub test()
    N1 = 3
    N2 = 4
    N3 = Sqr((N1) ^ 2 + (N2) ^ 2)
    MsgBox N3
End Sub
```

Comment: Any workaround for PPTVBA users? I just did `N1 * N1`

Comment: @BhaveshShaha Hi, please check the latest edit :)