# Why is Visio VBA Exponentiation not working?

Tags: vba, visio, exponentiation

Today Visio VBA is behaving differently.  debug.print 2^2 prints "2 2" and debug.print 5.5^2 gives an error message "Compile error:  Expected expression" while debug.print (5.5)^2 gives 30.25.

I don't remember ever seeing this before in the past probably 15 years of VBA programming, I expected to get 4 and 30.25

Comment: This is quite well covered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264287/vba-power-operator-not-working-as-expected-in-64-bit-vba

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA power operator (^) not working as expected in 64-bit VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264287/vba-power-operator-not-working-as-expected-in-64-bit-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Use `2 ^ 2`. The space is important.